# JQuery UI and event handling

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI widget which attaches to a div and then listens to specific controls inside it (set via options). The problem is that in my event listener, this refers to the control that changed, not the element the widget is attached to. So how can I access the widget element?

```
    _addressChanged: function () {
        $(this).data("address").requiresValidation = true;
    },

    _bindEventHandlers: function () {
        $(this.options.address1).bind("change", this._addressChanged);
        $(this.options.address2).bind("change", this._addressChanged);
        $(this.options.city).bind("change", this._addressChanged);
        $(this.options.zip).bind("change", this._addressChanged);
    },
```

Comment: Hey Rich, did my answer help you? If so, consider accepting it and we both get reputation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`this._on()` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-_on) to bind the handler. This method is provided by the jQuery UI widget factory and will make sure that within the handler function, `this` always refers to the widget instance.

```js
_bindEventHandlers: function () {
    this._on(this.options.address1, {
        change: "_addressChanged" // Note: pass the function name as a string!
    });
    ...
},
_addressChanged: function (event) {
    // 'this' is now the widget instance.
    // 'this.element', as suggested by sjsharktank, is the DOM element the widget was created on
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `this.element`?

From http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory:

> **this.element**
>
> The element that was used to instantiate the plugin. For example, if you were to do `$( "#foo" ).myWidget()`, then inside your widget instance `this.element` would be a jQuery object containing the element with id foo. If you select multiple elements and call `.myWidget()` on the collection, a separate plugin instance will be instantiated for each element. In other words, `this.element` will always contain exactly one element.

Comment: That won't work within an event handler that was bound via .bind() or on(). See my answer for the solution offered by the widget factory.