# Binding an internal event listener on a jQuery UI Widget

Tags: jquery-ui

#### TLDR;

I'm trying to bind the same way as an external handler, just on the inside of the jQuery UI Widget.

#### Details

For the purposes of triggering/listening to events inside a large/pluggable jQuery UI Widget, I'm attempting to use the widget element's `bind` and the widget's `_trigger`, but cannot seem to get it wired up properly.

The following code is from a coffeescript class inside the widget that has a back reference to it:

```
  bind: (type, fn) ->
    ### bind a callback through the widget's element ###

    # this doesn't work
    @widget.element.bind("#{@widget.widgetEventPrefix}#{type}", fn)

    # this doesn't work either
    @widget.element.bind(type, fn)
```

The following has no effect:

```
@widget._trigger('foo')
```

#### Reason

I'm binding to the wrong element.  I noticed that `@widget.element` is not the same element that is used as the reference outside the widget e.g. `@widget.element` !== `$('#bar').myWidget()`

#### Summary

External listeners have no problem binding/listening the same way via the `$('#bar').myWidget().bind('mywidgetfoo', () -> alert 'foo')`

I'm trying to bind the same way as an external handler, just on the inside of the widget.

## Question???

How should I be binding inside the widget so that both internal and external listeners are properly connected?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17672051/2363935) looks viable, but I'm not sure how I can adapt it given that I don't know how to adapt it, given it declares the event `type` and in my case, it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *FINALLY* figured this out, and it was as simple as missing the fact that handlers using `bind` to listen are **all lower case**.

So here is a sample of the code I use in an internal component base class to allow components to `bind` and `unbind` against the top level jQuery UI Widget, allowing me to use an event oriented architecture that uses the same events inside and outside the widget:

```
class Base

  constructor: (@widget) ->

  _fullyQualifiedEventName: (type) ->
    fullyQualifiedName = "#{@widget.widgetEventPrefix}#{type}".toLowerCase()
    fullyQualifiedName  

  bind: (type, fn) ->
    ### bind a callback through the widget's element ###
    fullyQualifiedName = @_fullyQualifiedEventName(type)

    @widget.element.bind(fullyQualifiedName, fn)

    console.log "bind(#{fullyQualifiedName}, #{fn.name})"

  unbind: (type, fn) ->
    ### unbind a callback from the widget's element ###
    fullyQualifiedName = @_fullyQualifiedEventName(type)

    @widget.element.unbind(fullyQualifiedName, fn)

    console.log "unbind(#{fullyQualifiedName}, #{fn.name})"
```

Whether a handler on the inside is bound to the `foo` event with `@bind('foo', fn)`, or externally with `$('#bar').myWidget().bind('mywidgetfoo', fn)`, or they passed in a handler via options in instantiation `{foo: () -> console.log 'options foo listener fired'}`, all listeners will now be triggered with `@widget._trigger('foo')`